# Why isn't my comment showing on the blog?

Tags: support, comments, blog

In the [recent blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here) regarding the official Stack Exchange iPhone app release, I posted a comment and it redirected me to the [comment link](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/#comment-92827). But it is not visible. When I tried to repost it, I got this error:

> Duplicate comment detected; it looks as though you’ve already said that!

First I thought it may take admin's approval to show the comment, But I remember I posted few comments before (in older blogs) which was published immediately. However, I waited for 24 hours to see whether my post is visible or not but still I couldn't find it. (and during this period I found other's comments which was posted after mine). I even tried to post it with different email id but still the same issue.

I have two links of my comments. [First one](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/#comment-92827) and [second](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/#comment-92828).

I tried even on [another blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/#comment-92829). But no luck.

What is the issue here?